# What is wrong with this usage of std::find_if?

Tags: predicate, c++

I get the following error when compiling the std::find_if function:

```
error C2451: conditional expression of type 'overloaded-function' is illegal
```

The code looks like this:

```
typedef std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<node> >::iterator nodes_iterator;

nodes_iterator node_iter = std::find_if(_request->begin(), _request->end(), boost::bind(&RequestValues::is_parameter, this));

bool RequestValues::is_parameter(nodes_iterator iter)
{
   return ((*iter)->name.compare("parameter") == 0);
}
```

It seems to have something to do with the predicate function passed to the `std::find_if`, however I cannot figure out what is wrong, can anybody help?

`node` is a `struct` containing some values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `_1`, not `this` when binding, and take a `value_type` as an argument of your function.

If this is a class or struct member function, then `bind(func, this, _1)` maybe? But if it is a class member function it should probably be static because it needn't state.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison function you provide to `find_if` should not take in an iterator, but rather the value that the iterator is pointing at (or even better, a const reference to it).  For example, when writing a predicate for `find_if` over a range of `int`s, the comparison should take in an `int` rather than `vector<int>::iterator`.  Changing your comparison function to work on `shared_ptr<node>`s might not fix all your errors, but it should at least account for some of them.

Answer (score 1):

That function's signature should be

```
bool RequestValues::is_parameter(boost::shared_ptr<node>);
```

i.e., it doesn't take an iterator, but the iterator's `value_type`.

Comment: @Tony: Sorry, I missed the target with that shot.